# Populate values based on another dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes as follows, where I create a new column for the unique id.

```
import pandas as pd

df1=pd.DataFrame({
                  'no1':[20,20,40,10,50],
                  'no2':[50,20,10,40,50]
                  })

df2=pd.DataFrame({
                  'no1':[20,20,40,10,50,10,20,40],
                  'no2':[50,20,10,40,50,40,20,10],
                  'no3':[20,50,10,20,40,20,40,10],
                  'no4':[50,50,40,20,10,20,10,40]
})

df1['id'] = df1.groupby(['no1', 'no2']).ngroup()
```

which gives the following:

```
    no1 no2 id
0   20  50  2
1   20  20  1
2   40  10  3
3   10  40  0
4   50  50  4
```

I want to create new columns and populate them based on the values in columns of `df2`. I would like to have the following:

```
    no1 no2 no3 no4 id1 id2
0   20  50  20  50  2   2
1   20  20  50  50  1   4
2   40  10  10  40  3   0
3   10  40  20  20  0   1
4   50  50  40  10  4   3
5   10  40  20  20  0   1
6   20  20  40  10  1   3
7   40  10  10  40  3   0
```

The values in `id1` are based on a combination of values in `no1` and `no2` and the values in `id2` are based on a combination of values in `no3` and `no4`.
Could someone suggest a way to do this in pandas?

Answer (score 1):

Just assign them separately

```
df2['id1'],df2['id2'] = df2.groupby(['no1', 'no2']).ngroup(), df2.groupby(['no3', 'no4']).ngroup()
df2
Out[124]: 
   no1  no2  no3  no4  id1  id2
0   20   50   20   50    2    2
1   20   20   50   50    1    4
2   40   10   10   40    3    0
3   10   40   20   20    0    1
4   50   50   40   10    4    3
5   10   40   20   20    0    1
6   20   20   40   10    1    3
7   40   10   10   40    3    0
```

Comment: I can see that this gives the required answer. However, is it guaranteed that the a particular combination will correspond to the same value in all three columns, i.e. column `id` in `df1` and columns `id1` and `id2` in `df2`?